# General question - copy, cut, paste

Tags: copy-paste

How do the applications transfer the copied strings into each other? Is this a clipboard usage? If so, how can i access the clipboard in a program?

Edit: I'm interested in Windows systems, I know a bit of C#, and C++.

Comment: It depends on the operating system, please clarify.

Comment: Also depends on the programming language you're intending to use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, cut-and-paste is usually done using the system-wide clipboard.

In both Windows Forms and WPF applications, there are (different) classes called 'Clipboard', which contain the stuff you need to access the system clipboard.

Basically, the clipboard allows you to put pretty much anything on to it, along with markers that say what format the data is in.  You can put the same data on in lots of different formats.   That's how, for example, you can cut and paste a part of a spreadsheet in Excel into Notepad - Excel has put the data onto the clipboard in both a native Excel format **and** a plain text format.